# Unicode friendly alphabetic pattern for python regex?

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for a pattern equivalent to \w, and which doesn't match numeric pattern.
I cannot use [a-zA-Z] because I would like it to match japanese kanjis as well.

Is there a way to write something like [\w^[0-9]] ?
Is there an equivalent of [:alpha:] in python regex?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
[^\W\d]
```

Throw out non-word characters and throw out digits. Keep the rest.

Comment: I honestly bow before your greatness :)

Comment: Excellent. This throws out ALL Unicode digit characters, not just the ASCII [0-9].